# magmi attribute_set ignored - always set to default

Tags: magento, magmi

I have started using magmi to import products, using the option `create new items & update existing ones`, however, when a new product is created, the `_attribute_set` seems to be ignored.
I have defined an attribute set in Magento called `Books`, which includes attributes such as ISBN, author.

Here is a sample from the CSV file (only the first few columns):

Header:

> sku,_store,_attribute_set,_type,categories,_product_websites,name

Product Line:

> ZZ001,,Books,simple,MyCategory/MySubCategory,base,Book Title

On the above example, ZZ001 is created, but with an attribute set of `Default`

Store is blank - is this a problem?

Someone else asked a question about this - but I didn't see a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Just looking at one of my csv files that works I have the column header as **attribute_set**, without the leading _ (and I have store also with out the leading _ and they're all set to admin).

Answer (score 1):

Please double-check and make sure your column names are correct.

`_store` should be `store`
`_attribute_set` should be `attribute_set`
`_type` should be `type`
`_product_websites` should be `websites`

Also for attribute sets, you must make sure that the attribute set is already created before attempting to import products under it.  Magmi does not automatically create attribute sets.

Comment: Ran into exactly this. Do you know of a documented reason why `attribute_set` becomes `_attribute_set`?

Comment: When you export from Magento, it usually produces these columns containing an appended underscore.  Magmi does not support the direct import of Magento generated CSV files, you need to be sure to format the CSV correctly following the Magmi documentation before importing with Magmi.